# Break for loop from completion handler

Tags: swift

I have 4 type of category: ["PR", "Pickup", "Recommend", "New"]

For each type I need to call to server to fetch articles.
The problem is that I want to stop fetching if I had enough 20 articles.
I don't want to handle every single callback. Is there a better way?

I'm using DispatchGroup but it doesn't work as expected. Here is my code:

```
let types: [FeedTimeline] = [.special, .pr, .pickup, .lastPost]
for type in types {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    self.getArticles(of: type, page: currentPage) { [unowned self] (articles) in
        self.articles.append(contentsOf: articles ?? [])
        self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        if self.articles.count >= 20 {
            self.currentSubType = type
            //I want to stop request here 
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post code. Where are you storing the retrieved articles?

Comment: I'm edited my post

Comment: Several people posted answers to your question. What became of it?

Comment: I solved my problem by using a different solution

Comment: You should post your solution in this forum so others might benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the `articles` `count` in `dispatchGroup's` `notify` `closure`, you need to do it before calling `getArticles(of:page:handler:)` method, i.e.

```
    types.forEach { (type) in
        if self.articles.count < 20 {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            self.getArticles(of: type, page: currentPage) {[unowned self] (articles) in
                self.articles.append(contentsOf: articles ?? [])
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
```

Next the `dispatchGroup's` `notify` `closure` goes like,

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it work. I ran your code, the for loop & `if self.articles.count < 20` ran 4 times before the article was fetched.

Comment: That's because the API hit is async. Do you need the `articles` to be added in order of the `types`?

Comment: Yes. I need it in order as the types array