# completionBlock be called before the operation done

Tags: swift, operation

I have some code here:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
let types: [FeedTimeline] = [.special, .pr, .pickup, .lastPost]
var operations: [Operation] = []
for type in types {
            
    let operation = BlockOperation {
        print("Working")
        self.getArticles(of: type, page: 1, completion: { (articles) in
            print("Fetched")
        })
    }
    operation.completionBlock = {
        print("Done")
    }
    queue.addOperation(operation)
```

After I ran the code above, I get the result below:

> Working
>
> Done
>
> Working
>
> Working
>
> Done
>
> Done
>
> Working
>
> Done

After a while I got 4 times of "Fetched". Why is that? How to make `completionBlock` only run if the API request (getArticles) done.

What I want is: `working` -> `fetched` -> `done` -> `working` .... so on

Comment: use semaphore .

Comment: I want every single operation will wait for execute until the before operation done

Comment: A block operation is synchronous. You have to subclass `Operation` to make it asynchronous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break for loop from completion handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550121/break-for-loop-from-completion-handler)

Comment: Kindle don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the operation continues executing (i.e. exits) once the call to `self.getArticles` has been executed, not after it has completed.

One way to fix this is to use [dispatch groups](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup). Try the following code:

```
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    let types: [FeedTimeline] = [.special, .pr, .pickup, .lastPost]
    var operations: [Operation] = []

    for type in types {

        let operation = BlockOperation {
            group.enter()
            print("Working")
            self.getArticles(of: type, page: 1, completion: { (articles) in
                print("Fetched")
                group.leave()
            })
            group.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
        }
        operation.completionBlock = {
            print("Done")
        }
        queue.addOperation(operation)
```

In this case the call to group.wait() will block until each call to group.enter() is matched by a call to group.leave(), meaning that the BlockOperation will wait until the call to getArticles has completed.

Note that you need to ensure that getArticles always executes the callback, if it doesn't (e.g. due to network timeout), the operation block will hang forever.

Comment: but this will block the current thread wont it?

Comment: No, the group.wait command blocks the thread running the BlockOperation (preventing the operation to complete before the call to self.getArticles executes its completion-block)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a subclass of `Operation` with overridden `isExecuting` and `isFinished` to tell the system when exactly your operation begins and when finishes.  Something like this:

```
class AsyncOperation: Operation {
    override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
        return true
    }

    private let _queue = DispatchQueue(label: "asyncOperationQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
    private var _isExecuting: Bool = false

    override var isExecuting: Bool {
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
            _queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._isExecuting = newValue
            }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
        }

        get {
            return _isExecuting
        }
    }

    var _isFinished: Bool = false

    override var isFinished: Bool {
        set {
            willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
            _queue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                self._isFinished = newValue
            }
            didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
        }

        get {
            return _isFinished
        }
    }
}
```

Then subclass your operation from this new class. I guess reading [this](https://maysamsh.me/2019/08/18/swift-operation-and-operationqueue/) helps if you want to do it with operation and operation queue.

Comment: Your asynchronous operation is not thread-safe. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561169/trying-to-understand-asynchronous-operation-subclass/48104095#48104095)

Comment: It's better but the linked answer is a comprehensive and **complete** implementation.